# Is it impossible to say "I am busy on every Monday"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is it impossible to say "I am busy on every Monday" ?

I was told that it's not a grammatically correct sentence.

Someone said "I am busy every Monday" is correct.

Is it true?

Why can't I use "On" in front of "Every Monday" ?

Comment: You have to use one or the other.  Either "on Mondays" or "every Monday" but not both.

Comment: You cannot say: *on every Monday*... If you want to say that you go somewhere *on every Monday* use *on Mondays* or *every Monday*, which are equal expressions. Basically *every Monday*=*on Mondays*

Comment: @Andrew I very much disagree. "I am busy on every Monday" is grammatically correct. It's just not colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

"On every" is not a normal idiomatic phrase in English.  As with most idioms, there's no "why" other than "that's how people talk".

Basically you have to use one or the other, either "on Mondays" or "every Monday".  These have *almost* the same meaning:

> I play tennis **on Mondays** (When I play tennis, it's on a Monday, and not usually any other day)
>
> I play tennis **every Monday** (I always play tennis on Monday, and possibly other days as well)

Answer (score 1):

You could say "I am busy Mondays" meaning EVERY Monday, or you could say "I am busy Monday" meaning just THIS Monday, not every one.  But you would not say "I am busy on every Monday"  because when you say "I am busy Mondays," it already means EVERY Monday.  Just one of those unfortunate things in English where the only explanation is "that's just the way it is..."  Obviously "Mondays" is plural so it means ALL the Mondays.